# AWS Java SDK DescribeLoadBalancersResult return empty Response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

The AWS Java API [DescribeLoadBalancersResult][1] returns Empty load balancers descriptions after providing the correct region codes and aws credentials. Ther are Loadbalancers in the AWS and same is returned via CLI

```
public void getELB(String accessKey, String secretKey, String region, String... elbids) throws Exception {
        AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient = new EC2Client().getELBClient(accessKey,
                secretKey, region);
        DescribeLoadBalancersResult describeLoadBalancersResult = amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.describeLoadBalancers();
        System.out.println(describeLoadBalancersResult);
        List<LoadBalancerDescription> balancerDescriptions = describeLoadBalancersResult.getLoadBalancerDescriptions();
        for (Iterator iterator = balancerDescriptions.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            LoadBalancerDescription loadBalancerDescription = (LoadBalancerDescription) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(loadBalancerDescription);
            
        }
    }
```

It output

```
{LoadBalancerDescriptions: [],}
```

Here is the Method of creating the `AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient`

```
public AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient  getELBClient(String accessKey, String secretKey, String region) throws Exception {
        AWSCredentialsProvider provider;
        if (accessKey != null && secretKey != null) {
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            provider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
        } else {
            provider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        }
        AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient client = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient(provider).withRegion(Regions.fromName(region));
        ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
        configuration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
        return client;
    }


  [1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancing/model/DescribeLoadBalancersResult.html
```